# why functions return Multidimensional Arrays but the result is a num?

Tags: javascript

when functions return Multidimensional Arrays(arrays is all num),but the result is a num?

```
function show(){
    return [1,2][1,2];
}
function show1(){
    return [0,1,2][1,2];
}
function show2(){
    return [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12][[0,1,2,[5,9,8,6][2,1,5,0],4,6][1,2,3]];
}
console.log(show());//undefined
console.log(show1());//2
console.log(show2());//5
```

Comment: show returns the 3rd (index 2) element of [1,2] == undefined ... show1 returns the 3rd (index 2) element of [0,1,2] == 2 ... show2 I'm not even going to try an understand, but you get the picture (I worked it out and 5 is correct :p )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are using bracket notation for getting an element from the arrays.

As an example the `show1` function returns 2 because:

`[0,1,2]` defines an array, 
and `[1,2]` is a bracket notation for getting an element from the array. The code snippet is equal to: `[0,1,2][2]`, as the *comma operator* returns the last operand which is 2.

You need to wrap the code snippet with `[]` for having an array with 2 elements:

```
[[0,1,2], [1,2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your syntax. In javascript (and other languages) 2 dimension array is an array of arrays so when you want to declare it in javascript you should do this:

```
var twoDimArray = [[1, 2], [3, 6]];
```